# 3 dimensional array sort Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have already read several posts here and on other sites about using a custom sort function on multidimensional arrays but can't work out how to implement them for this case...

I am trying to use the painters algorithm...

```
face_list[num_face][num_vertex] = [2d_x, 2d_y, z, light_intensity]
```

How do I write the sort function such that the face_list is sorted by z?

I have tried

```
a=a[2][2]

b=b[2][2]
```

For third value of third array but the browser doesn't like it.

The sequence of [num_face] is what I want changed.

I've been puzzling over this for two days now and would appreciate help!

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: What is the error you are getting. What does a and b look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method of sorting, yes it's a custom sort function, but they're great.
You get the values, in your case the `z` value, and keeps a list of the indices of each point, then sorts it by `z`.

Taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Example.3A_Sorting_maps

> ```
> // the array to be sorted
> var list = ["Delta", "alpha", "CHARLIE", "bravo"];
> // temporary holder of position and sort-value
> var map = [];
> // container for the resulting order
> var result = [];
>
> // walk original array to map values and positions
> for (var i=0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
>   map.push({    
>     // remember the index within the original array
>     index: i, 
>     // evaluate the value to sort
>     value: list[i].toLowerCase() 
>   });
> }
>
> // sorting the map containing the reduced values
> map.sort(function(a, b) {
>   return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
> });
>
> // copy values in right order
> for (var i=0, length = map.length; i < length; i++) {
>   result.push(list[map[i].index]);
> }
>
> // print sorted list
> print(result);
> ```

Comment: This looked promising but I then realised that it will not keep the vertices together. From the face_list[n][v] I need the vertices to stay ordered for each face. Its the faces I want to sort not the vertices.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you, despite my doubts an hour ago this answer did provide the direction which finally worked. I'd like to post the code but can't seem to work out how to post code in the comments box (yes I have read the help page "Indent four spaces to create an escaped <pre><code> block:" but can't work out how to do that.

Comment: @user1977132 Glad it could help. Btw you can update your original question and add the edits for your new code so others can benefit too

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

(corresponding jsBin is here : http://jsbin.com/olegoj/1/edit  )

```
// 3D points array.
var points=[];

var Vector=function(x,y,z) {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.z=z;
};

Vector.prototype.toString= function() {
  return (' x: ' + this.x + ' y: ' + this.y  + ' z : ' + this.z);
};

// returns a new vector translatedfrom ampVec * random 
Vector.prototype.createRandomShift= function(ampVec) {
    var thisRandom = Math.random()*0.9+0.1;
  return  new Vector(
      thisRandom*ampVec.x+this.x,
       thisRandom*ampVec.y+this.y,
        thisRandom*ampVec.z+this.z    );
};

var pointCount=20;

var pt = new Vector(Math.random()*100|0, Math.random()*100|0, Math.random()*100|0 );
var ampVec = new Vector(Math.random()*4-2, Math.random()*4-2, Math.random()*4 - 2);
var ampVecAmp = new Vector(Math.random()*2-1, Math.random()*2-1, Math.random()*2-1) ;

// fill the point array.
// based on the current point shifted randomly by ampVec
// ampVec itself is shifted randomly by ampVecAmp 
for(var i=0; i<pointCount; i++) {
   points.push(pt );
   pt=pt.createRandomShift(ampVec);
   ampVec=ampVec.createRandomShift(ampVecAmp);
}

// array of face. a face is an array of 3 point indexes.
var facelist=[];

var faceCount=10, i=faceCount;

// fill the face array
while(i--) {
    var thisFacePoints=[];
    var ip1 = 0;
    // 3 point indexes
    thisFacePoints.push(ip1=Math.random()*pointCount|0);
    thisFacePoints.push(Math.random()*pointCount|0);
    thisFacePoints.push(Math.random()*pointCount|0);
    facelist.push(thisFacePoints);
}

// returns the min z for a face
var minZ=function(f) {
    return Math.min(f[0].z, Math.min(f[1].z, f[2].z));
};

// returns the max z for a face                  
var maxZ=function(f) {
   return Math.max(f[0].z, Math.max(f[1].z, f[2].z));
};

// !!! sort the faces on Z !!!
facelist.sort(function(a,b) {
   if (maxZ(a) < minZ (b)) return 1;  // a fully below b
   if (minZ(b) < minZ(a) ) return -1;  // b fully below a
   // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   // in fact here is the tricky part :
   // here a and b overlap in Z.
  return trickyFaceZSort(a,b); 
 });

 // !!!!!! returns wether face a is < to face b when looking at Z (0,0,1).
//Required : a and b overlaps by Z.
var trickyFaceZSort= function(a,b) {
 // do some checks on projected(xi), projected(yi)  -> return 0 if no overlap
 // then you have the hardest part ahead : x,y and z overlap.
 return 0;
};

// Print sorted faces
for(var i=0; i<facelist.length; i++) {
    var fp=facelist[i];
console.log(' *** face ' + i + ' *** ');
console.log(' ** point 0 ' + points[fp[0]] + ' *** ');
console.log(' ** point 1 ' + points[fp[1]] + ' *** ');
console.log(' ** point 2 ' + points[fp[2]] + ' *** ');  
}
```